90 mins vs 60 mins meditation mostly Anapana
I am doing meditation for 1 hour . I am planning to go for 90 mins . Will there be any significant change ?Anyone have real experience ?
Follow up Why everyone asks to do twice , not once a day?

Fulltime practitioner, 1.5 -  2 hours 4 or more times per day continuously to get everything in this video clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGjjaqF4324&pp=ygUWUGFhdWsgRm9yZXN0IG1vbmFzdGVyeQ%3D%3D then you understand how to stop the suffering

If the mind as constant concentration, 90 minutes will make a big difference.
If the mind has constant hindrances, 90 minutes will not make a big difference.

do your mind remain as constant concentration i mean no distraction for even 5 mins

My point is if there is constant concentration; there will be constant calming or samatha. If there is constant calming, 90 minutes is important.

The Buddha doesn't talk about minutes of meditation, but does emphasize its importance. Monks would often meditate during the night.
The Noble Eightfold Path has Right Immersion as the eighth step, but there are seven others to be taken in context as well. Indeed, there are suttas that warn against getting too caught up in meditation. One of those suttas is MN8:

MN8:4.1: It’s possible that a certain mendicant, quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unskillful qualities, might enter and remain in the first absorption, which has the rapture and bliss born of seclusion, while placing the mind and keeping it connected.
MN8:4.2: They might think
MN8:4.3: they’re practicing self-effacement.
MN8:4.4: But in the training of the Noble One these are not called ‘self-effacement’;
MN8:4.5: they’re called ‘blissful meditations in the present life’.

In other words, abiding in bliss is nice, but when someone cuts in front of us while we drive, what often arises is anger, not bliss.  Use your meditation time to understand the root of that anger so that you can let it go. Gauge your progress not by minutes meditating, but in your daily contentment and resilience to adversity.

Yes.  In fact, I'd argue that 90 minutes is the bare minimum for samatha practice.  Most of the benefit occurs after the one hour mark.  There is a quality in quantity.  Even if you can't sustain perfect samadhi for the entire time, the effort you exert alone will benefit your practice.  Over time, you will grow into the full duration just like you grew into your one hour sit.
